# How can I set the text color of a label of a disabled input HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If the custom-switch is enabled:

- the label text color shall be green.

If the custom-switch is disabled:

- the label text color shall be red.

A button can enable the custom-switch and another can disable it through a JavaScript (JQuery) method call.

---

#### The Problem

It seems the color of the disabled label can not be modified. Although the same is working for the enabled label.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      /* If it is enabled */
      .exampleClass_label{
        color: green;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      /* If it is disabled */
      .myDiv2 .exampleClass_label{
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <button onclick="myEnable()">Enable!</button>
    <button onclick="myDisable()">Disable!</button>


    <div class="custom-control custom-switch myDiv">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
        id="exampleID_input_switch">
      <label class="custom-control-label exampleClass_label"
        for="exampleID_input_switch">
        Title of Switch
      </label>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      myDisable();

      function myEnable() {
        $(".myDiv").removeClass("myDiv2");
        $('.myDiv :input').attr('disabled', false);
      }

      function myDisable(){
        $(".myDiv").addClass("myDiv2");
        $('.myDiv :input').attr('disabled', true);
      }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to me looks like everithing is working check [here](https://codepen.io/cripava/pen/oNYqxRX) be sure that jQuey is loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

while you are adding `myDiv2` class you can just set the `pointer-events: none` which will act as `disabled`.

```
.myDiv2{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

just put the above code in your css.